# Is there predefined 2D point in C/C++ with predefined arithmetic operations?

Tags: c++, c, cython

I am currently writing a simulation, which works a lot with 2D points/vectors. Thus I find my self writing code, which looks like this:

```
double force_1[2] = {0.0, 0.0};
double force_2[2] = result_of_calculation();
force_1[0] = force_1[0] + force_2[0];
force_1[1] = force_1[1] + force_2[1];
```

Is there a class in C/C++, which can represent a 2D vector and (most important) has all basic arithmetic operations predefined ? I would like to do:

```
double force_1[2] = {0.0, 0.0};
double force_2[2] = result_of_calculation();
force_1 += force_2;
force_1 *= force_2;
```

More:
The simulation is not written in C but in Python.
I am working with Cython and I would like to drop my Numpy dependency.

```
force_1 = np.array((0.0, 0.0))
# type force_2 is np.ndarray
force_2 = result_of_calculation()
force_1 += force_2
force_1[1] = force_1[1] + force_2[1]
```

Comment: You can create one. Also consider a library - I know of GLM, which is designed for computer graphics.

Comment: maybe `std::valarray`

Comment: There's the complex number types from C99...

Comment: You could abuse `std::complex`

Comment: "_Is there a class in C_" - No, not a single one.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, C++ only, GLM would be the best choice.

Alternatively, if possible, [AVX - Advanced Vector Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)

For GCC have a look at this [Using Vector Instructions through Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)